# Azure VM shutdown schedule via nodejs SDK

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs, azure-node-sdk

I’m writing an Azure Function (nodejs) that will create a VM shutdown schedule on VMs that don’t have one.

I am having an issue however listing schedules. All of the *list** methods of the [Schedules interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/azure-arm-devtestlabs/schedules?view=azure-node-latest#list-string--string--object-) require the `labName` parameter, however, I don’t have a lab. VM shutdown schedules don’t require a lab.

Checking the actual ARM definition of this VM shutdown schedule there is no `labname` either:
[image]

The same issue is true if I try to create such a schedule via the SDK.
How do I do this if I don’t have a lab?

Comment: probably a bug, you dont need a labName for sure, but you can just to the api directly

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason it wasn't obvious to use this here: [GlobalSchedules interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/azure-arm-devtestlabs/globalschedules?view=azure-node-latest#listbyresourcegroup-string--object-)